# convert SQL create query to Django Model

Tags: django

I'm specifically having a problem with the following lines:

```
`created_at` datetime(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
`updated_at` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
```

Here is the full SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE `billing_package` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `start` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `expiry` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  `updated_at` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Django Model

```
class Package(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    expiry = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    price= models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    count = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

After running migrations with Django, when i check the database, there is no `default` value for `created_at` and `updated_at`?  How do i correctly do the following in a Django Model?

```
   `created_at` datetime(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
   `updated_at` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
```

Comment: The defaults are done by Django, not by the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I correctly do the following in a Django Model?

You don't. Django does the processing to obtain a default value. It will thus *not* set a default in the database model, but Django's ORM will update the fields accordingly.

You can however implement this by making a *raw query* in a migration file. You can create an empty migration file with:

```
python manage.py makemigrations --empty app_name
```

This will create a new file in the `migrations` directory of *`app_name`*. Next you you can write a raw SQL query by altering the file to look like:

```
# Generated by Django A.B on YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
from django.db import migrations

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('app_name', '0123_some_name'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL('ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER created_at SET DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)'),
        migrations.RunSQL('ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY updated_at datetime(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)')
    ]
```

This will update the database, although it can be different if you use another SQL dialect.